# Правильно ли использовать докер для размещения нескольких сайтов на сервере

Tags: mysql, nginx, docker

Всем привет. Сейчас на сервере установлено около 6 сайтов через docker-compose на каждый сайт своя отдельная конфигурация но она схожа, так как сервер маленький столкнулся с проблемой что больше 6 контейнеров на нем не поднять. Если переустановить сайты без докера, то когда возрастет нагрузка на 1 сайт, упадут остальные так как nginx и mysql будут перегружены. Хочу узнать ваше мнение как лучше все таки с docker или без.

Answer (score 0):

В современном продакшене никак без контейнеризация приложения, сама по себе контейнеризация помогает нам с деплоем, разработкой, развертыванием и все остальным присущем проблемам связанным с совместимостью. Но я думаю вы это и так знаете, я говорю это к тому что вы конечно же должны использовать докер. Я конечно не до конца понимаю в чем проблема поднять на одном сервере больше 6 сайтов, но сам факт поднятия на одном сервере стольких сервисов немного не верно, на мой взгляд.